# how to show angular's component Object in parent template?

Tags: angular

In parent component, I got child component Object.But how can I show this child component.
I try some ways and not works;
eg:
part of template
`html
<ng-template [ngComponentOutlet]='children[0]'></ng-template>
<!-- children is a component -->`

part of parent compenent
```typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef, ContentChildren, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ISelectItem } from './item-interface';
@Component({
    selector: 'zzj-table-tool-select',
    templateUrl: './table-tool-select.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./table-tool-select.component.scss']
})
export class TableToolSelectComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
    children: ISelectItem[] = [];
    @ContentChildren('child') child;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
    public addItem(item: ISelectItem) {
      this.children.push(item);
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log('--------');
      console.log(this.child)
    }
}
```

`part of child item component`
typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, ContentChild, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TableToolSelectComponent } from '../table-tool-select.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'zzj-select-item',
  templateUrl: './select-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-item.component.scss']
})
export class SelectItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) content: TemplateRef<void>;
  constructor(public selectPrtCom: TableToolSelectComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectPrtCom.addItem(this);
    console.log(this.content)
  }
}
```

```
How can I do this?

Comment: what happens when you put the child component tag <child-component> inside the parent's HTML? can you share a minimal stackblitz which recreates your issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Go  to the app.component.ts and add at the top of the file:

```
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';
Then open app.component.html and replace the content with this:
<h1>
  This is the parent component!
</h1>
<app-child></app-child>
```